# On setting Edit Text box text with respect to change in another Edit text and Vice versa in real time changing

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textwatcher

I have two entry boxes(Edit Text Box) In android layout, I am trying to set one edit text box's text to another Edit text box's text by calculating some value and Vice versa(getting text from second text box then calculate and add it to first text box) in real time(on current time of typing in edit box), I have seen some of the answers on 'On Text Change Listeners' and tried but might be due to focusing issue of edit boxes it is crashing.

Comment: Maybe supplying the crash log to help people understand your bug. P/s: onTextChangeListener() should work tho

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Adding text watcher at the same time may cause a problem (Recurring effect). But you can achieve your requirement by activating text watcher one at a time. While **edittext1** text changes we will remove text watcher for **edittext2** and we will set **edittext2** in `onTextChanged` of text watcher of **edittext1**. then we will reactivate text watcher of **edittext2** in `afterTextChanged` text watcher of **edittext1**. the same logic applies to **edittext1**.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        EditText editText1,editText2,editText3,editText4;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            editText1=findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            editText2=findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            editText3=findViewById(R.id.editText3);
            editText4=findViewById(R.id.editText4);
            editText1.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher1);
            editText2.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher2);
            editText3.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher3);
            editText4.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher4);
        }

        TextWatcher textWatcher1=new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                editText2.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher2);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                editText2.setText(editText1.getText());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                editText2.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher2);
            }
        };

        TextWatcher textWatcher2=new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                editText1.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                editText1.setText(editText2.getText());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                editText1.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher1);
                }
            };
          }

TextWatcher textWatcher3=new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                editText4.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher4);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                editText4.setText(editText3.getText());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                editText4.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher4);
            }
        };

        TextWatcher textWatcher4=new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                editText3.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher3);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                editText3.setText(editText4.getText());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                editText3.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher3);
                }
            };
          }
```

Comment: thanks George ..it helped but can you please elaborate how can I do it for Four edit boxes ... say edit box 1 changes on edit box 2 and vice versa(you mentioned) as it is change on edit box 3 changes 4 and vice versa on the same activity... how can I remove or add text change listener..I am kind of new to this stuff..thanks

Comment: You can use the same idea that applied with editText1 and editText2. anyway, I have updated the answer. please take a look.

Comment: thanks for giving your time to this